# Rails 4 OmniAuth Facebook NoAuthorizationErrorCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, omniauth

I'm running into an issue with facebook login in once I deploy to Heroku. I disabled sandbox mode by setting my "making the app available to the public". I can't quite tell if this is a facebook settings issue or an issue with my app. I've been searching hard for an answer and haven't been able to find any.

Heroku Logs:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/facebook/callback"

OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError (must pass either a `code` parameter or a signed request (via `signed_request` parameter or a `fbsr_XXX` cookie))
```

I've tried some other [strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370056/omniauth-strategies-facebook-noauthorizationcodeerror-must-pass-either-a-code) such as switching to gem "omniauth-facebook", "~> 1.4.1" but ran into a CSRF issue there.

I'm using:

```
  * oauth2 (0.9.4)
  * omniauth (1.2.2)
  * omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
  * omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.2)
```

My routes are pretty standard

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

And finally my JS

```
 $scope.login = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to say it was not pushing my private and secret keys to production. I hope this helps someone else.