# How to solve OmniAuth NoAuthorizationCodeError when using Facebook JS SDK in a React Flux App?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've built a full-stack app in React using Flux. I've been stuck for days on trying to get facebook login to work using the javascript SDK. Inside of a React component I have:

```
  signInToFacebook: function() {
    ApiUtil.signInToFacebook();
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                          // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="fb-login-button" onClick={this.signInToFacebook}>
        {"Sign in with Facebook"}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Basically, I have a div which when clicked calls a function "signInToFacebook", which then calls another function in ApiUtil called "signInToFacebook", which is the following:

```
var ApiUtil = {
  signInToFacebook: function() {
    FB.login(this.signInOmniAuth);
  },

  signInOmniAuth: function(response) {

    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/auth/facebook/callback',
      success: function() {
        console.log("returned in apiutil");
        debugger;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I click on the div, the ajax request is made, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error:

> OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError at
>
> ## /auth/facebook/callback
>
> > must pass either a `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)
>
> omniauth-facebook (3.0.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb, line
>   151

Here is the parsed request Header:

> Accept:*/* Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pt-BR;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4,de;q=0.2
>   Cache-Control:no-cache Connection:keep-alive
>   Cookie:_Project_session=K3o2K3NxbnBXZ2w4c1lqZXdtMFhoeFdtSndSSm95OEtEZGdVQVJnNkx0L2JobzVSZmh4MHM4VHN4OWo0dHJjU3p0dlV6ZHhIL3dleG9hOCtRazF0dmhCSWI5aGgvcTBaVXFvS0wzcXdIV1ZmMm9wTGZ2ZG81enBjcjR6Y0VnKzBUTThNR3RoM1ZnRkozMUQ0cnhkbzVnPT0tLStsamIzek01R2RRMWllKy9YMlVPSWc9PQ%3D%3D--60dad32af96176a6d60eb9c5b151513bab2169a3;
>   fbsr_1691421964447573=NvJPbYyDyKzi6NUQMUMCTWXi3QLVP6J9vG5OIfSBmT8.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
>   Host:localhost:3000 Pragma:no-cache Referer:http://localhost:3000/
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110
>   Safari/537.36
>   X-CSRF-Token:NKgNvTOCLRjE9l0lJwl3MF8yFfXH5LuLjG3NLrmD4I1FIgRoOzT7uN8rvyxNG4HSQ/2bKcVBojQ7blmuI+qWZQ==
>   X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

When I look at the request cookies, there is a fbsr_XXX cookie where XXX is my APP_ID.

I have tried using the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370056/omniauth-strategies-facebook-noauthorizationcodeerror-must-pass-either-a-code?rq=1), basically making my ajax request as follows:

```
  signInToFacebook: function() {
    FB.login(this.signInOmniAuth);
  },

  signInOmniAuth: function(response) {

    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/auth/facebook/callback',
      data: {signed_request: response.authResponse.signedRequest},
      success: function() {
        console.log("returned in apiutil");
        debugger;
      }
    });
  },
```

But I still get the same 500 error.

Comment: are you ever calling the `init` function on `FB`? looks like its being skipped.

Comment: should also move `(function(d, s, id){
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));` way outside your component to top level javascript

Comment: Aren't I calling init function on FB in componentDidMount?

Comment: I moved that portion of the code to application.html.erb in a <script> tag. Same problem as before.

Comment: Are you sure you have your App ID and App Secret in /config/initializers/omniauth.rb

Comment: Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['my_app_id_number_here'], ENV['my_app_secret_here']

end

Comment: @The1Fitz the above is my config/initializers/omniauth.rb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14489379/1536309

Comment: @BlairAnderson I think I have those proposed solutions:
1) To the ajax request above I add data: {signedRequest: response.authResponse.signedRequest} 2) I disabled sandbox mode (which as I understood it means making my app live), in either case I get the same problem as before

Comment: On the first comment to the first proposed solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370056/omniauth-strategies-facebook-noauthorizationcodeerror-must-pass-either-a-code/14489379#14489379

someone said "I've also noticed that in my case the fbsr_XXX cookie was present, except that was prefixed with a space (e.g. " fbsr_XXX"), which is preventing the omniauth gem code from locating the data that should already be stored in the cookie" When I look at the cookies, I too see fbsr_XXX, but I don't know how to tell if there is a space or how to solve the issue if there is a space.

Comment: I also tried adding a test user (someone different from myself, who is administrator), and logging in in both sandbox mode (development mode) and not sandbox mode. Same issue always...